# angel broking web socket API returns binary value that needs to be converted into json

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using smartapi.angel broking websocket. It returns binary type of value. I need to convert from binary to json using node js.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://smartapisocket.angelone.in/smart-stream', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlY1NzUzNjkiLCJyb2xlcyI6MCwidXNlcnR5cGUiOiJVU0VSIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc1NzkxMTYyLCJleHAiOjE3NjIxOTExNjJ9.vLCZ_yja1HtnrShXHnlfLuMm2-fftyvFo16ZQE4_4gvwAq9LTJXBJVjTp7afsL0xFPJaUyFJbvF9QZndy69NaA',
    'x-api-key': 'XXXX',
    'x-client-code': 'XXXXX',
    'x-feed-token': 'XXXXXX'
  }
});

ws.send(payload);

> Receive
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
   console.log(data); // THIS RETURNS BIONARY
 });
```

I need to convert response from binary to json / string.

Comment: .... What data are you receiving? what does it represent?

Comment: I got Binary value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have not missed the on open part? It is supposed to be like this:

```
ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send(payload);
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```